# How to disable speed search in Intellij IDEA in favour of hjkl navigation?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

In IntelliJ IDEA when the focus is on the Projects Tool Window every letter pressed starts the '[speed search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html)' functionality. It starts highlighting the files and folders which match the typed string.

How do I disable this feature?

I am using the VIM emulation and I would prefer to have h-j-k-l configured for navigating left-down-up-right. It looks like the documentation does not mention how to disable the speed-search.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IdeaVim doesn't yet support hjkl navigation in the project tree: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1042

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll subscribe for updates. Upvoted.